# I have an error with the findArray() function

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine

I need help, in my project in `symfony` I have a problem with the `findArray()` method.
I wanted to retrieve the contents of the session with the `array_keys($session>get('panier'))` function and use its result to query my database.
But only `symfony` returns this:

> Undefined method 'findArray'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

But if I do a var_dump on `array_keys($session->get('basket'))`, I find items in the session.
Apparently the findArray method is not recognized.
Here is the contents of my controller:

```
public function validationAction(){
       if($this->get('request')->getMethod()=='POST'){
           $this->setLivraisonOnSession();
       }

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
       $adress=$session->get('adresse');
       /*var_dump(array_keys($session->get('panier')));
       die();*/
       $produits=$em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier'))
                                                                               );

       $livraison= $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:UtilisateurAdresse')->find($adress['livraison']);
       $facturation= $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:UtilisateurAdresse')->find($adress['facturation']);

       return $this->render('SaressoSaressoBundle:Default:panierVerification.html.twig',array('produits'=>$produits,                                                                                                   'livraison'=>$livraison,                                                                                                   'facturation'=>$facturation,                                                                                                   'panier'=>$session->get('panier')));
   }
```

Merci d'avance pour vos réponses

Comment: findArray must be created in ProduitsRepository repository to work. You can use findBy alternative but the result is an object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this instead:

```
$produits = $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')
                    ->findBy(array_keys($session->get('panier')));
```

That should work.

---

EDIT #2

Sorry, my mistake try this Edit #2:

```
$produits = $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')
                    ->find($session->get('panier'));
```

---

EDIT#3

Also please then try this:

```
$produits = $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')
                        ->findOneBy(
                            array('id' => $session->get('panier'))
                        );
```

let me know the result.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I also had to think about this, and there ca returned  Unrecognized field: 0

Comment: See my EDIT #2. I see the problem, you are trying to findBy with an Array, and you can't do that. You need a `single` digit value.

Comment: It returns `Unrecognized field: 96` because the content of the session is array(0=>96).

Comment: Is `96' the Id? If so try `->find($session->get('panier'))` I'll modify my post if that is correct.

Comment: Yes exactly in my database, for the products entity, there is an ID=96

Comment: Updated my post. Try `->find( $session->get('panier') );`

Comment: Now it returns this: `The identifier id is missing for a query of Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Produits`

Comment: Can you try manually setting it to: `$produits = $em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')->find(1);` and see if that works? I'm wondering if: `$session->get('panier')` is a `string`?

Comment: Yes i do it, and when make `var_dump($produits)`, it returns an _objet_ and make `var_dump(array_keys($session->get('panier')))` so i got an array: `C:\wamp64\www\Saresso\src\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Controller\PanierController.php:258:
array (size=1)
  0 => int 96`;    and when 
 i do var_dump('$produits')`C:\wamp64\www\Saresso\src\Saresso\SaressoBundle\Controller\PanierController.php:265:
object(Saresso\SaressoBundle\Entity\Produits)[546]
  private 'id' => int 96 .....`

Comment: The solution you have proposed does not return an error but rather null. So it does not do what I want.
`var_dump ($ session-> get ( 'basket'));
Array (size = 2)
   96 => int 1
   95 => int 1
var_dump ($ products); Is null`

And even in the tuto that I follow, he did not use any special method.

There are links on the subjects where the method is used, but no one has this problem;

[link](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony2-probleme-recuperation-prixttc)
https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/panier-validation-symfony-3-probleme-besoin-daide
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve my problem by using a loop to browse the contents of the session and from there I retrieve the id of the products and then I interrogate my database. Here is the code with no need to use a QueryBuilder just with the find () method. `$produits=array();
       foreach(array_keys($session->get('panier')) as $prod){
           $produits[]=$em->getRepository('SaressoSaressoBundle:Produits')->find($prod);
       }`

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! I knew you would.